# Does recharging a battery at a lower temperature lower its internal resistance?

Tags: electricity, batteries

Does temperature affect the internal resistance of batteries? And does charging a "frozen" battery allow it to charge faster than a warm or room temperature battery?

Answer (score 4):

Internal resistance generally increases as you lower the temperature. This is because batteries generate current using a chemical reaction and the reaction generally goes slower at lower temperatures. [This article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_resistance) on Wikipedia claims the internal resistance of a manganese alkaline battery increases from 0.1 ohms at 40°C to about 0.9 ohms at -40°C. Car batteries, i.e. lead acid batteries, do the same as described [here](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/discharging_at_high_and_low_temperatures).

A cold battery will charge slower and will have a reduced capacity, so you want to charge at room temp if you can.

Comment: I think the reaction rate will increase with temperature. So, will a warm battery get charged faster, sir?